# User Binding Request with credentials in Lync Dump

Tags: network, voip, lync

I've dumped a call between two lync clients and saw that there were some UDP packets that look like this:

Server -> Client

```
1132    14.495362000    <serverip> <clientip>   STUN    146 Binding Request user: ????:????
```

Client -> Server:

```
1133    14.499136000    <clientip>  <serverip>  STUN    130 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: <serverip>:54019 user: ????:????
```

????:???? - ? is a character from the alphabet

If I read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3489) correctly this is not a security issue, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you need to enable `MESSAGE-INTEGRITY` mode for it to be secure. `MESSAGE-INTEGRITY` needs to enabled and supported on your STUN/TURN server.

Take a look at Microsoft's TURN/STUN RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766

Without `MESSAGE-INTEGRITY`, depending on the level of access of the attacker, a relfection attack might possible.

**Disclaimer**: It's been a while since I've dealt with Windows